# React/Gatsby: Conditionally wrap every two posts inside a div

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to wrap every two posts inside a container div. Below is what I tried, but unfortunately I get an error.

This is what I tried:
I have a variable called `postIndex`. While the posts are being iterated over with `posts.map(({ node }) => {...}`, I have a conditional if/else check to see if `postIndex` is odd or even with `if (postIndex % 2 == 0)` (check if `postIndex` is even) and `if (postIndex % 2 == 1)` (check if `postIndex` is odd).

If `postIndex` is even I render out only the opening `<div>` tag that is the container for the two posts. If `postIndex` is odd, then I render out only the closing `</div>` tag.

I get an error with this implementation, though. What is the right way to go about doing something like this?

Example of what I tried:

```
    let postIndex = 0

    return (
      <Layout>    
        {posts.map(({ node }) => {
          if (postIndex % 2 == 0) {
            postIndex++
            return (
               <div>
                <p>test</p>
            )
          } else if(postIndex % 2 == 1) {
            postIndex++
            return (
              <p>Test</p>
             </div>
            )
          }
        })
        }
      </Layout>
    )
```

Comment: I think you can find a solution with a for loop that iterate i+2 each time instead of using map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An opening tag without a closing tag is invalid JSX. You can probably do something like this below though. Also, you have access to the index of the array in a map, so you don't need to create a new variable.

```
return (
  <Layout>    
    {posts.map(({ node }, index) => {
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        return (
           <div key={index}>
            <p>{node}</p>
            {posts[index + 1] && <p>{posts[index + 1].node}</p>}
           </div>
        )
      }
    })
    }
  </Layout>
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take a good look at this when I get home and get back to you

Comment: thanks for also mentioning that `map` has `index`. This was really helpful.

Comment: I have two questions about this -- 1) what is the significance of `key = { index }` here? and 2) assuming `posts` contains 10 entries, how will `map` know that I want to go from 0 index to 2 index to 4 index, etc? I guess I should maybe consider looking into something other than `map` -- not sure.

Comment: Actually, I think I get this now -- on the indexes where `index % 2 != 0`, it skips that item. This is pretty cool. Thanks again.